# How to set shortcut key for Sketch 3 "Detach from Symbol"?

Tags: sketch-app

How to set shortcut key for "Detach from Symbol"?

[image]

Comment: I think this sketch plugin does what you want https://github.com/einancunlu/disconnect-for-sketch

Comment: @zholdas I try, but this not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps given below to add shortcut key for "Detach from Symbol" in Sketch-app:

1. Open **System Preferences** and click on **Keyboard**.
2. Go to the **Shortcuts Tab**, down to **App Shortcuts** in the list on the left, and click the “**+**” to add a new App Shortcut.
3. Select Sketch.app application. Menu Title : "**Layer->Detach from Symbol**". Enter your keyboard shortcut (alt+cmd+shift+d) and click Add.
4. Use your custom shortcut in Sketch-app to detach from symbol.

[image]

Source: [Majd Taby's medium post](https://medium.com/@jtaby/efficient-design-in-sketch-with-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-aec24d8f995)